# Why does Perl 6's string concatenation not like .WHAT?

Tags: raku

I'm puzzled about this bit of code where I apparently can't call the `WHAT` method in a string concatenation?

```
my $object = 'Camelia';

say $object;
say $object.WHAT;
say "^name: The object is a " ~ $object.^name;
say "WHAT: The object is a " ~ $object.WHAT;
```

The output shows that calling `^name` works (a metamethod from [Metamodel::ClassHOW](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW)), but Perl 6 is confused by `.WHAT` as if there's a precedence issue.

```
Camelia
(Str)
^name: The object is a Str
Use of uninitialized value of type Str in string context
Any of .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can stringify undefined things, if needed.  in block <unit> at meta_methods.p6 line 7
WHAT: The object is a
```

My Perl 6:

```
This is Rakudo version 2015.12-219-gd67cb03 built on MoarVM version 2015.12-29-g8079ca5
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `.WHAT` returns a type object, an undefined object

Like most routines/operators, concatenation assumes its arguments are defined. But the `.WHAT` in your last line returns a type object and a type object is not defined. So the result is a warning and stringification to the empty string.

---

If you want to concatenate an undefined object without generating a warning and instead stringify it into the object's type name you must explicitly `.^name`, `.gist` or `.perl` it eg:

```
say "The object is a " ~ $object.^name
say "The object is a " ~ $object.WHAT.gist
```

displays:

```
The object is a Str
The object is a (Str)
```

Comment: It seems really broken that it will stringify in some cases and not others.

Comment: the idea is that if you're concatenating a value, you're expecting it to be a proper value. If you're expecting to get an undefined value, you'd be using .perl and friends (if you want "(Str)") or .^name (if you want "Str").

Comment: @briandfoy I've rewritten my answer. Maybe my new answer will make more sense.

Comment: You're old answer made sense. It's the situation that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @briandfoy `say` calls `.gist` on all of it's arguments. So it isn't actually stringifying.

Comment: say takes it's argument and does something implicit to turn it into a string. I call that stringifying. It's designed to do that.

Comment: say takes its argument and calls `.gist` which is guaranteed to return an Str even when it is called on an undefined value. It (`.gist`) also provides a means for giving any class a presentation logic (tabular output, for instance) which is definitely not what you would expect when you `$t.Str` or `~$t`. In those latter cases, you are hooking in to the core logic of the class that converts the object into a string. So no, .gist is not stringification in the same sense as coercing to .Str is.

Comment: Just for clarity, the problem in the original question isn't `say`. The code `my $undefined; my $foo = $undefined ~ 'bar'` demonstrates the same issue.

Comment: The point is that it is not an issue: concatenating an undefined value is going to cause a warning. Calling `.gist` on one will not. I've come to appreciate that there is a display logic pattern for objects (`$query-result.gist`) that I can provide that is completely different than what happens in string context (let's say, `class DB::Result { ... method Str { self.id } }`)

Comment: @ab5tract Yes, sorry, while I added my last comment after you added yours I intended it for other readers, not you. In fact I've upvoted your latest comment because "concatenating an undefined value is going to cause a warning ... calling .gist on one will not" so precisely and helpfully clarifies what's going on. I'm going to leave it for now but may return and update my answer to include more or less exactly that sentence.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @raiph :)

Answer (score 7):

[A quote](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-01-04#i_11825310) from Perl 6's IRC channel, user FROGGS:

> .WHAT gives you back a type, which is meant to warn if you interpolate or concat it or do math with it

In your example, `$object` is a `Str`, so `$object.WHAT` gives you the `Str` type.

In other words it's like writing:

```
say "WHAT: The object is a " ~ Str;
```

Edit: It seems your real question is "Why does Perl 6's string concatenation not like types?"

As others have mentioned, types are undefined and concatenation works on defined values. As Perl 6's warning message says, you need to use any of .^name, .perl, .gist to stringify undefined things.

These two will work because `say` uses `.gist` to stringify:

```
say Str;

say "The object is ", Str;
```

Comment: The problem is that it stringifies in other cases. But, going to IRC to find language oddities isn't going to help most people.

Comment: I don't know if this has been driven home enough already, but `say $object.WHAT;` is not simply being stringified. `say` is calling `.gist` on the object it is given, because `say` is obligated to represent objects in some form of human-viewable format. If you need to stringify use `print` instead, and you'll see it act consistently.

Comment: @Timbus, I understand that, but imagine being the guy who has to explain this in front if a room of people. That's a bit of a messy situation for people to remember.

Comment: I would explain that say inspects objects using .gist ? This doesn't seem hard: It's fairly analogous to ruby's p vs puts. By your logic in another comment, data dumper stringifies arguments differently too. But you wouldn't complain about that.

Comment: It's not explaining say that's the the problem. It's explaining the entire design of the language and allowing people to expect reasonable things rather than lots of special cases. This is already one of the main dislikes of Perl 5.

Comment: @briandfoy: Every Perl 6 value (at runtime) has a type, including undefined values.  (When you say `my Str $x;`, `$x` is initialized to the undefined value of type `Str`, not a generic 'undefined' value).  The undefined value of a particular type is then used at runtime to represent / refer to that type (rather than having a separate value).  So `$x.WHAT` returns `undef`, but with the same (run-time) type as `$x`.  Then, if you call `.new()` on an undefined value, it DWYW as far as acting like a class method.